# Accessing a value defined in an IF clause in a class

Tags: scala, class

I define a class like this

```
class foo {
  var a = false
  private def fooFunc() = {
    a = true
    "AAAA"
  }
  if (!a) { val d = fooFunc() }
}
```

and I instantiate it as

```
val myFoo = new foo
```

For sure the function fooFunc is executed but I can't access to d. Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Make it a `lazy val` in `foo` and forget about `a`.

Comment: Forget about `var` more generally (except in Akka Actors).

Comment: `d` exists only in the scope of your conditional expression

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `d` because it's defined in the scope of the `if` block, not in the scope of the class itself.

What about replacing

`if (!a) { val d = fooFunc() }`

by

`lazy val d = if (!a) Some(fooFunc()) else None`